# Out of memory in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, out-of-memory

I have a spring boot application that can run out of memory when processing very large uploaded files. I'm encountering this when running `./gradlew bootRun` and using embedded tomcat.

Is there a gradle option or some other configuration I can set in a `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` to set the maximum memory allowed for the spring boot application? I'd like to have something in a configuration file or the build.gradle file itself, so it would work for all developers.

I've tried setting `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx12000m` in `gradle.properties`, but seems to have no effect.

Comment: `-Xmx` is not an option?

Comment: I've tried setting it in gradle.properties (see edit), but maybe I'm not doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

- There are a few Gradle properties that can speed up your builds a bit.

  ```
   org.gradle.parallel=true
   org.gradle.daemon=true
   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
  ```
- If you want to add more memory to your tomcat you should change the following lines in `setenv.sh` script on your tomcat directory under `bin/`:

  ```
  export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m"
  export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx8192m"
  export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
  ```

Comment: (before your edit) OK, that I think is parsing it, becuase i'm getting a build error indicating that it's an invalid maximum heap size, for everything I try

Comment: Do I need quotes around the args or not? And, I believe I need more than 1024 megs, given then large files i'm uploading.